# Weather barrier for concrete block to wood transition

Tags: framing, waterproofing, masonry, water-damage, house-wrap

I have a concrete block garage with a single-car-size door that I've framed in.  The goal is to cover the whole area with siding.  I've applied housewrap to the wood portion but I'm not certain how to attach the Tyvek to the block to seal it's edge.

Comment: Installation information is here: https://www.dupont.com/content/dam/dupont/products-and-services/construction-materials/building-envelope-systems/documents/K-16160_Commercial_Mechanically-Fastened_WRB_Installation_Guidelines.pdf